# Drupal 10 Webform form element key is not editable

Tags: php, drupal-modules, drupal-10

I am new to Drupal 10, when I create a webform element, it is not possible to edit the FORM_KEY[image]

How can enable the option to edit the Form element key after creating the element?

I thought the following would nice idea:
Navigate to the webform you want to edit.

Click on the "Build" tab to access the form builder.

Find the form element for which you want to edit the Form key.

Click on the form element to select it.

Look for an option or field labeled "Form key" or something similar in the form element settings or configuration.

Edit the Form key as needed.

Save your changes.

It does not work, anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to edit and change the FORM_KEY only when you initially create it.

If you have access to code, you can change it in the specific YML configuration file of the webform by manually replacing the FORM_KEY and then re-importing the configuration file. But remember this is not advisable.

As of now, **this cannot be achieved from the form builder UI**